# Python create function in a loop capturing the loop variable

Tags: python, lambda

What's going on here?  I'm trying to create a list of functions:

```
def f(a,b):
    return a*b

funcs = []

for i in range(0,10):
    funcs.append(lambda x:f(i,x))
```

This isn't doing what I expect.  I would expect the list to act like this:

```
funcs[3](3) = 9
funcs[0](5) = 0
```

But all the functions in the list seem to be identical, and be setting the fixed value to be 9:

```
funcs[3](3) = 27
funcs[3](1) = 9

funcs[2](6) = 54
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

lambdas in python are closures.... the arguments you give it aren't going to be evaluated until the lambda is evaluated.  At that time, i=9 regardless, because your iteration is finished.

The behavior you're looking for can be achieved with functools.partial

```
import functools

def f(a,b):
    return a*b

funcs = []

for i in range(0,10):
    funcs.append(functools.partial(f,i))
```

Comment: I agree. Partial application is the way to go here.

Comment: here partial(f,i) stands for partial(f,b=i) not partial(f,a=i). so it's not the same thing as the original post. Partial function application 'from the right' (http://www.gossamer-threads.com/lists/python/dev/715103) has been rejected two times.

Answer (score 15):

Yep, the usual "scoping problem" (actually a binding-later-than-you want problem, but it's often called by that name). You've already gotten the two best (because simplest) answers -- the "fake default" `i=i` solution, and `functools.partial`, so I'm only giving the third one of the classic three, the "factory lambda":

```
for i in range(0,10):
    funcs.append((lambda i: lambda x: f(i, x))(i))
```

Personally I'd go with `i=i` if there's no risk of the functions in `funcs` being accidentally called with 2 parameters instead of just 1, but the factory function approach is worth considering when you need something a little bit richer than just pre-binding one arg.

Comment: I haven't seen this one before.  Kind of neat.

Comment: @ars, bit of an overkill for most cases actually (in Python), but it IS what one would naturally do in (say) Scheme, so I guess it _is_ kinda neat;-).

Comment: Right, I can't immediately think of a case where I would prefer it, but  a fun construction nonetheless.  :-)

Comment: There is one case where this naturally pops up: when you use map(range..., lambda i: ...)  instead of for loops and list comprehensions. Functional code in general is very good at avoiding capture bugs because you only capture immutable state

Answer (score 10):

There's only one `i` which is bound to each lambda, contrary to what you think.  This is a common mistake.

One way to get what you want is:

```
for i in range(0,10):
    funcs.append(lambda x, i=i: f(i, x))
```

Now you're creating a default parameter `i` in each lambda closure and binding to it the current *value* of the looping variable `i`.

Answer (score 2):

All the lambdas end up being bound to the last one. See this question for a longer answer:

[How do I create a list of Python lambdas (in a list comprehension/for loop)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/452610/how-do-i-create-a-list-of-python-lambdas-in-a-list-comprehension-for-loop)

Answer (score 2):

Considering the final value of `i == 9`

Like any good python function, it's going to use the value of the variable in the scope it was defined.  Perhaps `lambda: varname` (being that it is a language construct) binds to the name, not the value, and evaluates that name at runtime?

Similar to:

```
i = 9
def foo():
    print i

i = 10
foo()
```

<sup>I'd be quite interested in finding out of my answer is correct</sup>