# How can I define functions in a for loop?

Tags: python, list, function, loops, for-loop

I'm trying to define a function of 3 unknown variables (k,m,c) but let's say I have to define it 100 times due to a different frequency f each time. Can I do this in a for loop in python and store all the functions in a list such that they are callable later?

This is what I have so far

```
index = -1
f_t = []
for f in inputs[:,0]:
   index = index +1
   def F_analytic(k, m, c):
      F_t = k*m*c*f 
      return F_t
   f_t.append([])
   f_t[index].append(F_analytic)
```

but what I get in turn is a list of functions which are not callable:

```
Out[58]: 
[[<function __main__.F_analytic>],
[<function __main__.F_analytic>],
[<function __main__.F_analytic>],
[<function __main__.F_analytic>],
[<function __main__.F_analytic>],
...
... 
[<function __main__.F_analytic>],
[<function __main__.F_analytic>],
[<function __main__.F_analytic>]]
```

and the error is:

```
TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
```

Any help? 
Thank you!

Comment: Wait. You want to call a function with different parameters each time, but still can's see why do you want to define a function 100 times

Comment: Why not make `f` a parameter as well to your function?

Comment: ...and if you insist on having gazillion functions, see [`functools.partial`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.partial)

Comment: Well the above is an extract of a rather complicate optimization process wherwe I have a constant value that is obtained from 100 different inputs of f. The function that I have to optimize also changes for every f. This is why I'm using this approach.

Comment: The functions are perfectly callable (although they might not due what you expect, due to late binding). The problem is that they are put into a list of lists, rather than a simple list. The exception comes from incorrect code to access the contents, not from the function object itself. This should have just been closed as a typo; and this is a good example of why [mre]s and [debugging](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) are important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

① You are nesting lists although you just want a flat list (of functions).  See the answer of @BartoszKP on that.

② You want to create functions based on local variables.  You can do this using lambdas, as @Harsh is proposing, or you can do it using defaulted variables:

```
def F_analytic(k, m, c, f=f):  # notice the f=f here!
    F_t = k*m*c*f 
    return F_t
```

③ You should consider whether having a list of functions really is what you want (as @Wooble already pointed out).

Comment: Thank you! As of now, a list of functions is what I want! because what I have to optimize later is the sum of the square of the differences between the function (that changes with f) and a constant value (which is different for each f)!

Answer (score 2):

No, what you have is a list of lists of functions, with each inner list having 1 function.

Replace

```
f_t.append([])
f_t[index].append(F_analytic)
```

with

```
f_t.append(F_analytic)
```

(Although honestly, this whole approach seems rather suspicious; any reason you don't want one function with 4 parameters instead of 100 with 3?)

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are creating a list of lists, you can call each function object like this:

```
f_t[0][0](1,2,3)
```

Alternatively, just create a list of functions:

```
f_t = []

for f in inputs[:,0]:
    index = index +1
    def F_analytic(k, m, c):
        F_t = k*m*c*f 
        return F_t
    f_t.append(F_analytic)
```

And as noted by other answers and comments, this all seems a rather strange approach. Do you really need to do this? :)

Answer (score -1):

Sorry i dont think i answered the question properly, try this approach:

```
f_t = []
for f in input[:,0]:
    f_t.append(lambda k, m, c: k*m*c*f)
```

You can call the functions easily by:
lets say you want to call the first one:

```
f_t[0](k,m,c)
```

Where k,m,c are your variables

Comment: If using a lambda, you can do this in a list comprehension.

Comment: This won't work - `f` will have the value of last iteration _in all_ functions - see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1107243/281545

Answer (score -1):

Let's clean this code up:

```
#instead of an index counter, python provide `enumerate`
# so that you can have the counter as part of your loop
#index = -1
f_t = []
for index, f in enumerate(inputs[:,0]):
#   index = index +1
   def F_analytic(k, m, c):
      #these two lines are redundant. You're just returning an expression
      # so this whole function can be a lambda
      F_t = k*m*c*f 
      return F_t
   #why are you creating an inner list for each index position,
   # and then appending the function to it?
   #even if you wanted to have the inner list, you could do it in one step
   f_t.append([])
   f_t[index].append(F_analytic)
```

If we make the specified changes, we end up with:

```
f_t = [(lambda k, m, c: k*m*c*f) for f in inputs[:,0]]
```

Of course a much simpler approach would be simply to calculate the inputs to the product, including `f`, and multiply directly.

Comment: This won't work - `f` will have the value of last iteration _in all_ functions - see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18915672/281545