# What do lambda function closures capture?

Tags: python, lambda, closures

Recently I started playing around with Python and I came around something peculiar in the way closures work. Consider the following code:

```
adders=[None, None, None, None]

for i in [0,1,2,3]:
   adders[i]=lambda a: i+a

print adders[1](3)
```

It builds a simple array of functions that take a single input and return that input added by a number. The functions are constructed in `for` loop where the iterator `i` runs from `0` to `3`. For each of these numbers a `lambda` function is created which captures `i` and adds it to the function's input. The last line calls the second `lambda` function with `3` as a parameter. To my surprise the output was `6`.

I expected a `4`. My reasoning was: in Python everything is an object and thus every variable is essential a pointer to it. When creating the `lambda` closures for `i`, I expected it to store a pointer to the integer object currently pointed to by `i`. That means that when `i` assigned a new integer object it shouldn't effect the previously created closures. Sadly, inspecting the `adders` array within a debugger shows that it does. All `lambda` functions refer to the last value of `i`, `3`, which results in `adders[1](3)` returning `6`.

Which make me wonder about the following:

- What do the closures capture exactly?
- What is the most elegant way to convince the `lambda` functions to capture the current value of `i` in a way that will not be affected when `i` changes its value?

---

<sub>For a more accessible, practical version of the question, specific to the case where a loop (or list comprehension, generator expression etc.) is used, see [Creating functions (or lambdas) in a loop (or comprehension)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3431676/creating-functions-in-a-loop). This question is focused on understanding the underlying behaviour of the code in Python.</sub>

<sub>If you got here trying to fix a problem with making buttons in Tkinter, try [tkinter creating buttons in for loop passing command arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10865116/) for more specific advice.</sub>

<sub>See [What exactly is contained within a obj.__closure__?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14413946/) for technical details of **how** Python implements closures. See [What is the difference between Early and Late Binding?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10580) for related terminology discussion.</sub>

Comment: Dealing with closures in Python means reading <a href="http://code.activestate.com/recipes/502271/">this article</a>.

Comment: I have had this problem in UI code. Drove me nuts. The trick is to remember that loops do not create new scope.

Comment: @detly But if they don't create a new scope then why does `i` leave the namespace after the loop is complete. What a headache.

Comment: @TimMB How does `i` leave the namespace?

Comment: @detly Well I was going to say that `print i` wouldn't work after the loop. But I tested it for myself and now I see what you mean - it does work. I had no idea that loop variables lingered after the loop body in python.

Comment: @TimMB - Yeah, that's what I meant. Same for `if`, `with`, `try` etc.

Comment: There should be a way to thumb-up a tag (lambda) to make sure this question comes up as a related question every time someone asks about lambda.

Comment: This is in the official Python FAQ, under [Why do lambdas defined in a loop with different values all return the same result?](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#why-do-lambdas-defined-in-a-loop-with-different-values-all-return-the-same-result), with both an explanation and the usual workaround.

Comment: By the way, I've never understood why people think this is strange behavior. The function captures the `i` variable. If it didn't do that, Python closures wouldn't be closures. (It's especially baffling when people claim "Python doesn't have real closures" _because_ of this…) I can understand expecting loops (and other blocks) to create a scope if you're coming from, say, C or C++, but it seems like a lot of people don't have that expectation and are still confused…

Comment: @abarnert: I think closing the function using a value rather than a reference would still be a "real closure", it just wouldn't be the same thing as Python does. FWIW, the Wikipedia article does say that a closure binds its open variables either to values or to storage locations. It doesn't say that binding to a storage location is a closure whereas binding to a value is something different (what?)

Comment: @SteveJessop: See the first paragraph of [Lexical environment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_programming)#Lexical_environment) farther down the page, which explains that in imperative languages, closures have to be "by reference". Python makes this a bit confusing, because it has mutable values which have their own inherent memory location, but it also has assignment statements that don't mutate values but rather mutate the environment—but assuming you want assignment statements to work, the "location" that matters is the name, not the place in memory.

Comment: @abarnert: so in C++, lambdas with `[&]` are closures (albeit of limited lifetime) and lambdas with `[=]` are not closures? That choice of definition isn't going to confuse anyone ;-) And In Python before `nonlocal`, assignment *didn't* work for captured variables in nested functions, so were they closures then, or is read-only binding by reference to the lexical scope sufficient to be a closure? I wonder if trying to apply lambda calculus in this way to imperative languages is in point of fact a waste of effort, and better would be to invent new terminology...

Comment: "If you can say it code, then say it in code. Otherwise, use a comment." You made it here and figured it out, but for those looking at your code after you, how about a comment like this:


`# WARNING: Creating a lambda in a loop! Don't let the loop variable sneak into the lambda's closure.`

Comment: @detly Wouldn't there still be doubts even if the loop created a new scope? Because I think it's clear that `i` is shared for all iterations, even if the loop creates a new scope. For me, it seems the crux of the matter is that `i` is captured, and not the value of `i`.

Comment: @flow2k I agree. I think detly's first comment is popular not because it offers a complete explanation, but because it points out an essential fact about Python, which may trip up folks accustomed to the Java and C++ family of languages.

Comment: I decided this question is not actually a duplicate, because it's useful for closing other questions that where the closure variable is modified in other ways (not just by being a loop iteration variable). The other question is a bit more specific and intended for solving a practical problem.

Answer (score 229, accepted):

> What do the closures capture exactly?

Closures in Python use lexical scoping: they remember the name and scope of the closed-over variable *where* it is created. **However**, they are still *late binding*: the name is looked up *when* the code in the closure is used, not when the closure is created. Since all the functions in your example are created in the same scope and use the same variable name, they always refer to the same variable.

There are at least two ways to get early binding instead:

1. The most concise, but not strictly equivalent way is the [one recommended by Adrien Plisson](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2295372/181765). Create a lambda with an extra argument, and set the extra argument's default value to the object you want preserved.
2. More verbosely but also more robustly, we can create a new scope for each created lambda:

   ```
   >>> adders = [0,1,2,3]
   >>> for i in [0,1,2,3]:
   ...     adders[i] = (lambda b: lambda a: b + a)(i)
   ...     
   >>> adders[1](3)
   4
   >>> adders[2](3)
   5
   ```

   The scope here is created using a new function (another lambda, for brevity), which binds its argument, and passing the value you want to bind as the argument. In real code, though, you most likely will have an ordinary function instead of the lambda to create the new scope:

   ```
   def createAdder(x):
       return lambda y: y + x
   adders = [createAdder(i) for i in range(4)]
   ```

Comment: Python has static scoping, not dynamic scoping.. it's just all variables are references, so when you set a variable to a new object, the variable itself (the reference) has the same location, but it points to something else. the same thing happens in Scheme if you `set!`. see here for what dynamic scope really is: http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/articles/code_blocks.shtml .

Comment: Option 2 resembles what functional languages would call a "Curried function."

Comment: Solution 2 is better. I prefer it over the default parameter. It is more logical and less dependent on the specific way Python is designed. A second lambda provides local variables that function like a closure.  

Comment: Pedantically, closures [are the implementation technique which enable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_%28computer_programming%29) lexical scoping to work with late binding in languages where functions are first-class objects, such as Python. Dynamically scoped languages don't have or need them, because they can just do the same dynamic scope resolution they always would - looking up the name by working backwards through the call stack.

Answer (score 326):

you may force the capture of a variable using an argument with a default value:

```
>>> for i in [0,1,2,3]:
...    adders[i]=lambda a,i=i: i+a  # note the dummy parameter with a default value
...
>>> print( adders[1](3) )
4
```

the idea is to declare a parameter (cleverly named `i`) and give it a default value of the variable you want to capture (the value of  `i`)

Comment: +1 for using default values. Being evaluated when the lambda is defined makes them perfect for this use.

Comment: +1 also because this is the solution endorsed by [the official FAQ](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#why-do-lambdas-defined-in-a-loop-with-different-values-all-return-the-same-result).

Comment: **This is amazing.** The default Python behaviour, however, is not.

Comment: This just doesn't seem like a good solution though... you are actually changing function signature just to capture a copy of the variable. And also those invoking the function can mess with the i variable, right?

Comment: @DavidCallanan we are talking about a lambda: a type of ad-hoc function you typically define in your own code to plug a hole, not something you share through an entire sdk. if you need a stronger signature, you should use a real function.

Comment: @AdrienPlisson Fair enough, I never really thought that message through haha.

Answer (score 53):

For completeness another answer to your second question: You could use [partial](http://docs.python.org/library/functools.html#functools.partial) in the [functools](http://docs.python.org/library/functools.html) module.

With importing add from operator as Chris Lutz proposed the example becomes:

```
from functools import partial
from operator import add   # add(a, b) -- Same as a + b.

adders = [0,1,2,3]
for i in [0,1,2,3]:
    # store callable object with first argument given as (current) i
    adders[i] = partial(add, i) 

print adders[1](3)
```

Answer (score 34):

Consider the following code:

```
x = "foo"

def print_x():
    print x

x = "bar"

print_x() # Outputs "bar"
```

I think most people won't find this confusing at all. It is the expected behaviour.

So, why do people think it would be different when it is done in a loop? I know I did that mistake myself, but I don't know why. It is the loop? Or perhaps the lambda?

After all, the loop is just a shorter version of:

```
adders= [0,1,2,3]
i = 0
adders[i] = lambda a: i+a
i = 1
adders[i] = lambda a: i+a
i = 2
adders[i] = lambda a: i+a
i = 3
adders[i] = lambda a: i+a
```

Comment: It's the loop, because in many other languages a loop can create a new scope.

Comment: This answer is good because it explains why the same `i` variable is being accessed for each lambda function.

Comment: I don't think the confusion is because of the loop, because even with a new scope, the value would still change. I think the confusion is because of the `lambda` - rather, because of *the fact that a closure is created* for names that the `lambda` looks up in the enclosing scope. Because Python's functions are first-class objects, it's easy to have the intuition that the `lambda` should "know" everything it needs to at creation time - like how, when we instantiate a class, `__init__` assigns values to `self` attributes, and `self` functions as a namespace that is bound early.

Comment: Of course, in the example here, we see the flaw in that illustrated by the late lookup of a global. But when I first encountered this problem, years and years ago, I think that I expected the global namespace to be a special case and that local and enclosing namespaces wouldn't behave that way. After all, it's *possible to leave* those scopes, right? So you'd have to bind early to avoid the problem, right? If `adders[1](3)` doesn't give `4`, *why doesn't it raise a `NameError`* for the out-of-scope `i` if we `return` the `adders` and use them elsewhere? The answer, of course, is the closure.

Answer (score 6):

Here's a new example that highlights the data structure and contents of a closure, to help clarify when the enclosing context is "saved."

```
def make_funcs():
    i = 42
    my_str = "hi"

    f_one = lambda: i

    i += 1
    f_two = lambda: i+1

    f_three = lambda: my_str
    return f_one, f_two, f_three

f_1, f_2, f_3 = make_funcs()
```

What is in a closure?

```
>>> print f_1.func_closure, f_1.func_closure[0].cell_contents
(<cell at 0x106a99a28: int object at 0x7fbb20c11170>,) 43
```

Notably, my_str is not in f1's closure.

What's in f2's closure?

```
>>> print f_2.func_closure, f_2.func_closure[0].cell_contents
(<cell at 0x106a99a28: int object at 0x7fbb20c11170>,) 43
```

Notice (from the memory addresses) that both closures contain the same objects. So, you can *start* to think of the lambda function as having a reference to the scope. However, my_str is not in the closure for f_1 or f_2, and i is not in the closure for f_3 (not shown), which suggests the closure objects themselves are distinct objects.

Are the closure objects themselves the same object?

```
>>> print f_1.func_closure is f_2.func_closure
False
```

Comment: NB The output `int object at [address X]>` made me think the closure is storing [address X] AKA a reference. However, [address X] will change if the variable is reassigned after the lambda statement.

Answer (score 2):

In answer to your second question, the most elegant way to do this would be to use a function that takes two parameters instead of an array:

```
add = lambda a, b: a + b
add(1, 3)
```

However, using lambda here is a bit silly. Python gives us the `operator` module, which provides a functional interface to the basic operators. The lambda above has unnecessary overhead just to call the addition operator:

```
from operator import add
add(1, 3)
```

I understand that you're playing around, trying to explore the language, but I can't imagine a situation I would use an array of functions where Python's scoping weirdness would get in the way.

If you wanted, you could write a small class that uses your array-indexing syntax:

```
class Adders(object):
    def __getitem__(self, item):
        return lambda a: a + item

adders = Adders()
adders[1](3)
```

Comment: Chris, of course the above code have nothing to do with my original problem. It's constructed to illustrate my point in a simple way. It is of course pointless and silly.

Answer (score 0):

create adder in a function to capture the value:

```
def create_adder(i):
    return lambda a: i + a


if __name__ == '__main__':
    adders = [None, None, None, None]

    for i in [0, 1, 2, 3]:
        adders[i] = create_adder(i)

    print(adders[1](3))
```

Answer (score -1):

One way to sort out the scope of `i` is to generate the lambda in another scope (a closure function), handing over the necessary parameters for it to make the lambda:

```py
def get_funky(i):
    return lambda a: i+a

adders=[None, None, None, None]

for i in [0,1,2,3]:
   adders[i]=get_funky(i)

print(*(ar(5) for ar in adders))
```

giving `5 6 7 8` of course.

Comment: There were already multiple answers showing this technique. I don't understand what this answer is supposed to add.

Comment: There were not multiple answers using this. On careful review of the other answers I see it mentioned at the end of Mark Shawabkeh's answer.