# list of lambdas in python

Tags: python, list, lambda

I have seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/452610/how-do-i-create-a-list-of-python-lambdas-in-a-list-comprehension-for-loop), but i still cannot get why such simple example does not work:

```
mylist = ["alice", "bob", "greta"]
funcdict = dict(((y, lambda x: x==str(y)) for y in mylist))
funcdict['alice']("greta")
#True
funcdict['alice']("alice")
#False
funcdict['greta']("greta")
#True
```

How is it different from:

```
[(y, y) for y in mylist]
```

Why `y` is not evalueated within each step of iteration?

Comment: Why do you expect `y` to be evaluated: it's a temporary variable inside a list comprehension.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `y` in the body of the `lambda` expression is just a name, unrelated to the `y` you use to iterate over `mylist`. As a free variable, a value of `y` is not found until you actually call the function, at which time it uses whatever value for `y` is in the calling scope.

To actually force `y` to have a value at definition time, you need to make it local to the body via an argument:

```
dict((y, lambda x, y=z: x == str(y)) for z in mylist)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
((y, lambda x: x==str(y)) for y in mylist)
```

`y` inside the lambda is not bound at the time of the genration expression defined, but it's bound when it's called; When it's called, iteration is already done, so `y` references the last item `greta`.

One way to work around this is to use keyword argument, which is evaluated when the function/lambda is defined:

```
funcdict = dict((y, lambda x, y=y: x == y) for y in mylist)
funcdict = {y: lambda x, y=y: x == y for y in mylist}  # dict-comprehension
```

or you can use `partial`:

```
funcdict = {y: partial(operator.eq, y) for y in mylist}
```

`y` is evaluated while the `mylist` is iterated.