# Python list of lambda functions

Tags: python, function, lambda

Say I need to build **n** lambda functions, and put them into a list:

```
n = 6
lamd_list = [lambda x: x * i for i in range(n)]
```

Here `x` is input of the lambda functions, and the `i` is intended to be fixed to *0~5* in the list. However, when I run:

```
lamb_list[0](3)
```

The output would be *15* (3 * 5) instead of *0* (0 * 5). How can I modify the code to make it do as I intended?
Note that here the `n` is a variable (not fixed), so I can't do the loop manually. Also, I don't want `i` as an input to the lambda function.

Comment: The answer by @chepner is very clear and easier to understand than answers below the [duplicated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/452610/how-do-i-create-a-list-of-python-lambdas-in-a-list-comprehension-for-loop) question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The value of `i` is not fixed when you defined the function, but when you *call* the function. You can fix it, but I would recommend *not* using lambda expressions at all. Instead, define a function that *creates* your function when called; it makes the scoping easier to handle.

```
def make_function(i):
    def _(x):
        return x * i
    return _

func_list = [make_function(i) for i in range(n)]
```

The difference here is that the `i` in the function that `make_function` returns is not a global variable, but the value of the parameter `i` when `make_function` is called.

Compare to another possible solution

```
lambd_list = [lambda x, unused=i: x * unused for i in range(n)]
```

which requires an otherwise unused parameter to be added to each function. The difference here is the default value of `unused` *is* evaluated at the same time as the lambda expression.