# How to generate a list of functions which still take an input

Tags: python, list, function

I'm looking to generate a list of similar but different functions, within a for loop. A MWE (which doesn't achieve the goal) would be as follows:

```
def generic(a, n):
    return a + n

def make_funs():
    N = 5
    functions_out = []
    for n in range(N):
        functions_out += [lambda x : generic(x, n)]
    return functions_out

funs = make_funs
```

The goal would be that to get

```
funs[0]
> result = {function}
print(funs[0](1))
> 1
print(funs[2](1))
> 2
```

and so forth. The current code above returns `5` for any `x` I put into `print(funs[x](1))`, implying that all the functions in my `funlist` are being created with `n = 4`.

Note that this question is related to, yet meaningfully different from the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/452610/how-do-i-create-a-list-of-python-lambdas-in-a-list-comprehension-for-loop). There, the lambda functions being creater only take one input variable, and so treats the `x` as I need to treat the `n` here. The desired output of that question is a list of numbers, my desired output is a list of functions.

Comment: [`from functools import partial`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial) … `functions_out.append(partial(generic, n=n))`

Comment: Did you mean: `functions_out.append(lambda x, n=n : generic(x, n))`?