# multiprocessing.pool cannot be accelerated in tf.data

Tags: python, tensorflow, multiprocessing, tensorflow-datasets

I want to use `multiprocessing.pool` in `tf.data` to speed up my augmentation function. But the result is slower than normal for loop.

multiprocessing.pool cost about: 72s

normal for loop cost about: 57s

My environment: `python3.6`, `tensorflow-gpu2.4.0`, `Ubuntu20.04`

Below is my code, what am I doing wrong?

Prerequisite thanks!

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from functools import partial
import multiprocessing

INPUT_SHAPE = (2000,6)
OUTPUT_SHAPE = (200,6)


def resizing(i ,data, enable, choice):
    if i==0:
        overlap=0
    else:
        overlap= 5 if enable >= 0.5 else 0
    if choice == 0:
        return [np.mean(data[i-overlap: i+10+overlap,0]),
                np.mean(data[i-overlap: i+10+overlap,1]),
                np.mean(data[i-overlap: i+10+overlap,2]),
                np.mean(data[i-overlap: i+10+overlap,3]),
                np.mean(data[i-overlap: i+10+overlap,4]),
                np.mean(data[i-overlap: i+10+overlap,5])]
    elif choice == 1:
        return [np.std(data[i-overlap: i+10+overlap,0]),
                np.std(data[i-overlap: i+10+overlap,1]),
                np.std(data[i-overlap: i+10+overlap,2]),
                np.std(data[i-overlap: i+10+overlap,3]),
                np.std(data[i-overlap: i+10+overlap,4]),
                np.std(data[i-overlap: i+10+overlap,5])]
    elif choice == 2:
        return [np.max(data[i-overlap: i+10+overlap,0]),
                np.max(data[i-overlap: i+10+overlap,1]),
                np.max(data[i-overlap: i+10+overlap,2]),
                np.max(data[i-overlap: i+10+overlap,3]),
                np.max(data[i-overlap: i+10+overlap,4]),
                np.max(data[i-overlap: i+10+overlap,5])]
    elif choice == 3:
        return [np.min(data[i-overlap: i+10+overlap,0]),
                np.min(data[i-overlap: i+10+overlap,1]),
                np.min(data[i-overlap: i+10+overlap,2]),
                np.min(data[i-overlap: i+10+overlap,3]),
                np.min(data[i-overlap: i+10+overlap,4]),
                np.min(data[i-overlap: i+10+overlap,5])]

def resize_data(data, pool_obj):

    choice = tf.random.uniform(shape=(), minval=0,maxval=4,dtype=tf.int64).numpy()
    enable = tf.random.uniform(shape=(), minval=0,maxval=1,dtype=tf.float64).numpy()
    new_data = pool_obj.map(partial(resizing, 
                                    data=data,
                                    enable=enable, 
                                    choice=choice), 
                            range(0,2000,10))
  # new_data = []
  # for i in range(0,2000,10):
  #     new_data.append(resizing(i ,data, enable, choice))
    
    return np.array(new_data)


def augmentation(data, labels, pool_obj):
    def aug(data):
        data = data.numpy()
        
        ...      

        # 2000 resize to 200
        data = resize_data(data, pool_obj)
        
        ...
        
        return tf.convert_to_tensor(data, tf.float64)

    data = tf.py_function(aug, [data], [tf.float64])[0]
    data.set_shape(OUTPUT_SHAPE)
    return data, labels

def test(trainDS):
    for d in trainDS:
        X, y = d
        print(i, X.shape, y.shape)
        

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool_obj = multiprocessing.Pool()
    trainDS = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(getDataSet_Path())
    trainDS = (
        trainDS
        .map(load_data, num_parallel_calls=tf.data.AUTOTUNE)
        .cache()
        .shuffle(300, reshuffle_each_iteration=False)
        .map(partial(augmentation, pool_obj=pool_obj), num_parallel_calls=tf.data.AUTOTUNE)
        .batch(128, drop_remainder=True)
        .prefetch(tf.data.AUTOTUNE)
    )
    
    test(trainDS)
```

Comment: Why not just use `num_parallel_calls` argument of `.map` ?

Comment: @bluesummers , I have used `tf.data.AUTOTUNE` in `.map`, can I set something else here?

Comment: Yeah, you can set it to any number you like - and it uses your cores. So when you use `num_parallel_calls` you don't actually need multiprocessing as you are already utilizing your cores efficiently

Comment: Maybe I need to reconstruct the content of my function with `tf` to effectively accelerate it?

Comment: @Linminxiang, we have to remove all `numpy` and `if` things from all functions inside `map` not to accelerate but to make it work properly.

Comment: @AlexeyTochin , Ok, let me try, I am not very familiar with `tf` yet.

Comment: @Linminxiang, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69709804/how-to-randomly-select-from-set-of-functions-in-tensorflow-using-tf-function/70323219#70323219) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70332161/tensorflow-what-is-the-difference-between-using-tf-greater-and-simply-greater/70367665#70367665) must help you,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TensorFlow Dataset API is already equipped with built in multiprocessing. Just use `num_parallel_calls` parameter in `map` and `prefetch` feature without any pythonic multiprocessing tools. Besides, pass only TensorFlow style functions  to `map` that can be converted to graph. In particular, avoid using pythonic `if` blocks, try `tf.cond`, `tf.where` and etc. instead. Numpy routines are also not recommended, use TensorFlow analogous. Follow guides like
[this](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/data).

Comment: Thank you very much for your comments. When I replaced most of `if else` and `numpy` with tensor, the execution efficiency improved a lot.