# Iteratively generate restriction of multivariate function using Python

Tags: python, function, math, lambda

I'm trying to write a function that generates the restrictions of a function `g` at a given point `p`.

For example, let's say `g(x, y, z) = 2x + 3y + z` and `p = (5, 10, 15)`. I'm trying to create a function that would return `[lambda x : g(x, 10, 15), lambda y: g(5, y, 15), lambda z: g(5, 10, z)]`. In other words, I want to take my multivariate function and return a list of univariate functions.

I wrote some Python to describe what I want, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to pass the right inputs from `p` into the lambda properly.

```
def restriction_generator(g, p):
    restrictions = []
    for i in range(len(p)):
        restriction = lambda x : g(p[0], p[1], ..., p[i-1], p[x], p[i+1], .... p[-1])
        restrictions.append(restriction)
    return restrictions
```

Purpose: I wrote a short function to estimate the derivative of a univariate function, and I'm trying to extend it to compute the gradient of a multivariate function by computing the derivative of each restriction function in the list returned by `restriction_generator`.

Apologies if this question has been asked before. I couldn't find anything after some searching, but I'm having trouble articulating my problem without all of this extra context. Another title for this question would probably be more appropriate.

Comment: Do you want to do this for a function of three variables or the general case of n variables?

Comment: General case of n variables. 
ACA provided a great approach below, but I'd love to see more ways of tackling the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since @bandicoot12 requested some more solutions, I will try to fix up your proposed code. I'm not familiar with the `...` notation, but I think this slight change should work:

```py
def restriction_generator(g, p):
    restrictions = []
    for i in range(len(p)):
        restriction = lambda x : g(*p[: i], x, *p[i+1:])
        restrictions.append(restriction)
    return restrictions
```

Although I am not familiar with the `...` notation, if I had to guess, your original code doesn't work because it probably always inputs `p[0]`. Maybe it can be fixed by changing it from `p[0], p[1], ..., p[i-1]` to `p[0], ..., p[i-1]`.

Comment: This is great! I was looking for a short lambda expression. 
The ... notation was just to help express what I was going for, but it didn't work. 
There's a slight bug in the code, which is resolved by changing the lambda to
`lambda x, i=i : g(*p[: i], x, *p[i+1:])`
The bug is explained in the posts below, just pasting for reference:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3431676/creating-functions-or-lambdas-in-a-loop-or-comprehension
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/452610/how-do-i-create-a-list-of-lambdas-in-a-list-comprehension-for-loop?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 1):

try something like this:

```py
def foo(fun, p, i):
    def bar(x):
        p[i] = x
        return fun(*p)
    return bar
```

and

```py
def restriction_generator(g, p):
    restrictions = []
    for i in range(len(p)):
        restrictions.append(foo(g, p, i))
    return restrictions
```

Comment: Nice! This was less tricky than I thought; I shouldn't have focused on using a lambda for this. Thanks for the help :)