# pyCurl WRITEFUNCTION callback with parameters

Tags: python, pycurl

I am using pyCurl with the following line to call a function with the data of the connection:

```
conn.setopt(pycurl.WRITEFUNCTION, on_receive)
```

Is there anyway I can pass more parameters to `on_receive` function, such as:

```
conn.setopt(pycurl.WRITEFUNCTION, on_receive, parameter_1, parameter_2)
```

Thanks,

Joel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only straight-forward way I know would be to have a separate springboard function to call your actual function with the additional parameters. A lambda function or function pointer in other words, if the parameters are ok to be constant.

```
connn.setopt(pycurl.WRITEFUNCTION, lambda data: real_impl(data, param1, param2))
```

Comment: Do `lambda data, p1=param1, p2=param2: real_impl(data, p1, p2))` to avoid bugs like: http://stackoverflow.com/q/139819/4279