# Generating a list of functions in python

Tags: python, list, lambda

I have the following python code that generates a list of anonymous functions:

```
basis = [ (lambda x: n*x) for n in [0, 1, 2] ]     
print basis[0](1)
```

I would have expected it to be equivalent to

```
basis = [ (lambda x: 0*x), (lambda x: 1*x), (lambda x: 2*x) ]
print basis[0](1)
```

However, whereas the second snippet prints out 0 which is what I would expect, the first prints 2. What's wrong with the first snippet of code, and why doesn't it behave as expected?

Comment: related question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/139819/4279

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use a default parameter to create a closure on n

```
>>> basis = [ (lambda x,n=n: n*x) for n in [0, 1, 2] ]     
>>> print basis[0](1)
0
```

Comment: This technique is frequently used to pass methods as callback functions.  It looks something like `register_event_handler(event=evt, callback=lambda cbVar1, cbVar2, s=self: s.handle_evt(cbVar1, cbVar2))`.

Answer (score 4):

Because it's "pass by name".

That is, when the `lambda` is run, it executes `n*x`: `x` is bound to `1` (it is a parameter), `n` is looked up in the environment (it is **now 2**). So, the result is 2.

Comment: This doesn't explain why the same behaviour is exhibited when we use a generator comprehension instead, which doesn't "leak" `n` into the `locals()`. AFAICT, the value of `n` is looked up from the lambda's `.func_closure`, and it's not at all clear how this magically refers to whatever `n` last referred to when `n` doesn't exist any more.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that in the first example, each lambda is bound to the same `n` -- in other words, it is capturing the variable, not the variable's value. Since `n` has the value of 2 at the end of the loop, each lambda is using the value 2 for `n`.

Apparently you can use default parameters to solve this problem:

```
basis = [ (lambda x,n=n: n*x) for n in [0, 1, 2] ]
print basis[0](1)
```

Since default parameter values are constants, the `n` on the right side of `n=n` will be evaluated each time through the loop to give you a new captured value.

Comment: Any suggestions on how to fix that?

Comment: celil: I edited my answer to offer a suggested fix, but it's not very elegant.

Comment: Default parameters might not be elegant, but they're a heck of a lot easier to look at than explicit partial evaluation like I used to do: `basis = [(lambda n:(lambda x: n * x))(n) for n in range(3)]`. :/ The default parameter isn't a "constant" in the sense of being immutable, but it does get evaluated and bound into the lambda's `.func_defaults`. Closure parameters do too, but apparently in a more magical way...

Comment: Karl: By "constant" I mean that the expression is evaluated once and never changes. Of course of that expression evaluates to a reference then you can change the object it refers to, but you can't change the reference itself.

Answer (score 0):

I want to help with the understanding of the comment from Karl Knechtel ( Dec 13 '10 at 7:32). The following code shows how using the generator, the original lambda definition gives the intended result, but it does not using list or tuple:

```
>>> #GENERATOR
... basis = ( (lambda x: n*x) for n in [0, 1, 2] )  
>>> print(type(basis))
<type 'generator'>
>>> basis = ( (lambda x: n*x) for n in [0, 1, 2] ) 
>>> print([x(3) for x in basis])
[0, 3, 6]
>>> #TUPLE
... basis = tuple( (lambda x: n*x) for n in [0, 1, 2] )
>>> print(type(basis))
<type 'tuple'>
>>> print([x(3) for x in basis])
[6, 6, 6]
>>> #LIST
... basis = list( (lambda x: n*x) for n in [0, 1, 2] )
>>> print(type(basis))
<type 'list'>
>>> print([x(3) for x in basis])
[6, 6, 6]
>>> #CORRECTED LIST
... basis = list( (lambda x, n=n: n*x) for n in [0, 1, 2] )
>>> print(type(basis))
<type 'list'>
>>> print([x(3) for x in basis])
[0, 3, 6]
```