# Generate dynamic methods in a class

Tags: python, python-2.7, code-generation

I want to have a class with dynamic methods.

From these arrays:

```
prefix = ['android','iphone','blackberry'] 
method = ['AddToPush','DelFromPush','GetPushMessages']
```

I want to create a class like:

```
class MobileManager(object)

    def __init__(self):
        self.mobileLib = MobileLib()

    def androidAddToPush(self, args):
        self.mobileLib.AddToPush(args, 'android')

    def iphoneAddToPush(self, args):
        self.mobileLib.AddToPush(args, 'iphone')    

    def blackberryAddToPush(self, args):
        self.mobileLib.AddToPush(args, 'blackberry') 

   [...]
```

How can I have these methods generated/created at runtime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your set of prefixes/methods is defined at init time, you can try something like this:

```
class MobileManager(object):
    def __init__(self):
        for prefix_name in prefix:
            for method_name in method:
                func = lambda self, args: getattr(self.mobileLib, method_name)(args, prefix)
                full_method_name = "%s%s" % (prefix, method_name)
                setattr(self, full_method_name, func)
        ...
```

If your dynamic methods get more complicated, the lambda will soon be limited, though.

Comment: Will it work like this: self.mobileLib.method_name(args, prefix) ?

Comment: In Your code You have line:
 func = lambda self, args: self.mobileLib.AddToPush(args, prefix)
'AddToPush' should be from method array.

Comment: It won't work: 1. drop `self` from `func()` parameters (you bind it to a concrete instance, not a class). 2. all `func` will use the last value of `method_name`. [You don't want that](http://stackoverflow.com/q/139819/4279).

Comment: `setattr(self, prefix+method_name, make_func(getattr(self.mobileLib, method_name), prefix))` should fix it, where `make_func = lambda func, prefix: lambda args: func(args, prefix)`

Comment: This one is working!
`make_func = lambda func, prefix_name: lambda args: func(args, prefix_name)
 setattr(self, prefix_name+method_name, make_func(getattr(self.mobileLib, method_name), prefix_name))`
  
*Thanks a lot!*

Answer (score 0):

Or why not inherate

```
class MobileManager(object)

    def __init__(self):
        self.mobileLib = MobileLib()

    def AddToPush(self, args, platform=None):
        self.mobileLib.AddToPush(args, platform)

class Android(MobileManager):
    def __init__(self):
        MobileManager.__init__(self)

    def AddToPush(self, args):
         MobileManager.AddToPush(args, platform="android")
```

Answer (score 0):

Dynamic methods are often the wrong approach leading to confusing code.

Here, I'd do this:

```
class Mobile(object):
    def add_to_push(self, args):
        ....
    def del_from_push(self, args):
        ...
    def get_push_methods(self, args):
        ...
```

And in your Manager:

```
class MobileManager(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.android = Mobile()
        self.blackberry = Mobile()
        self.iphone = Mobile()
```

Now, instead of `manager.mobileLib.add_to_push(args, 'android')`, you would write `manager.android.add_to_push(args)`.

You can even dispatch dynamically if you have a platform variable: `getattr(manager, platform).add_to_push(args)`.

If you want different behaviour for the 3 types of platform you can make subclasses of Mobile (perhaps AndroidMobile, BlackberryMobile and IPhoneMobile).

When a new platform appears (perhaps windows7) it's obvious how to change the code to support it.